# How to quickly determine whether a poset is a lattice?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, lattices, order-theory

Recently I encountered an interesting problem while studying discrete mathematics:

> Give the pseudo code to judge whether a poset $(S,\preceq)$ is a lattice, and analyze the time complexity of the algorithm.

I am an algorithm beginner, and I am not familiar with various advanced algorithms. I have no idea about this problem at present, but I have some thoughts as follows:

- Partially ordered sets can be transformed into **Hasse diagrams**, the algorithm to solve this problem may be a graph-related algorithm.
- To determine whether a poset is a lattice, each pair $\{a,b\}$ in the poset must be considered, so will it be a graph traversal algorithm?

Could you provide some specific ideas for this problem? Or even further, could you give the corresponding pseudo code?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The speed of such an algorithm will probably depend on how the poset is encoded in the input. Some natural encodings are: the Hasse diagram, either as an adjacency list or adjacency matrix, or its transitive closure (again, ajacency list or matrix). The input could also be an oracle which allows to test if $a\preceq b$ for any $a,b\in S$. What kind of input did you have in mind?

Comment: @Tassle I have considered that in a partially ordered set, not every two elements are comparable. If we use the adjacency matrix to represent the poset, there may be a large number of zero elements in it, so I prefer the adjacency list. Would you like to help me further to solve the problem? (BTW, I am not very familiar with the concept of transitive closures, and may not be able to give a correct judgment.)

Comment: By transitive closure of the Hasse diagram I simply mean the graph which has oriented edges between every two comparable elements. If the input is given as one of the encodings which I mentioned, it is pretty easy to solve the problem in $O(|S|^4)$ time. I might think about it a bit and post an answer if I have a good one.

Comment: @Tassle You mentioned that it's easy to solve the problem in $O(|S|^4)$ time, if I take the adjacency list(transitive closure) as input, what kind of algorithm should I use?